# Правильно ли расставлены запятые и как пишется «так же» в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, cслитно-раздельно

*Идеально подходит в качестве подарка, а так же, как атрибут для праздника.*

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно.

Правильно:

*Идеально подходит в качестве подарка, а также как атрибут для праздника.*

[**Также**, *нареч.* и *союз* (он также согласен), но *нареч. с частицей* **так же** (он так же думает, как ты).](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5&all=x)

Перед ***как*** не нужна запятая: значение ***в качестве***, но

[так же как (и)](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&all=x)!